# Change enumeration naming conversion when generating C# code from WSDL file

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

In a .NET Core project, I want to import a WSDL file using the Add Connected Service > WCF provider dialog.

The WSDL file contains some enum types, so that C# enums will be generated. For example:

```
<xs:simpleType name="RevenueRecognitionRuleName">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="Recognize upon invoicing" />
    <xs:enumeration value="Recognize daily over time" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Is compiled to:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.2")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://x.com/")]
public enum RevenueRecognitionRuleName
{
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Recognize upon invoicing")]
    Recognizeuponinvoicing,
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("Recognize daily over time")]
    Recognizedailyovertime,
}
```

It's nice that the generator removed all spaces so the enum names are in valid format. But they're not so pretty. Since I am unable to change how the service works, Camel Cased string values are not possible. I can only change the generator or the generated code.

Can I configure somehow the generator to use CamelCased enum format? The dialog doesn't offer such option, somewhere else?

Is there any extra XML attribute that I could add to the WSDL file which the generator is able to detect and use? It would be better to modify the WSDL than the generated code.

Comment: Based on [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe), it's likely not possible to configure the generator for this.

Comment: Yes, you cannot change the generated code or WSDL at will. WCF services can also provide channel factory calls. In this case, the client can call the service without the WSDL of the server.